# Set font size of CLinkCtrl

Tags: mfc

Is it possible to set the font size of a CLinkCtrl? I tried the following code, but it does nothing!

EDIT: Oops, forgot to include my attempt:

```cpp
CFont* aboutFont=nullptr;

BOOL AboutDlg::OnInitDialog(){
    SpecialDlg::OnInitDialog();
    if(aboutFont==nullptr){
        aboutFont=new CFont();
        aboutFont->CreateFont(
        20,                        // nHeight
        0,                         // nWidth
        0,                         // nEscapement
        0,                         // nOrientation
        FW_NORMAL,                 // nWeight
        FALSE,                     // bItalic
        FALSE,                     // bUnderline
        0,                         // cStrikeOut
        ANSI_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
        DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
        L"Arial");
    }
    ((CLinkCtrl*)GetDlgItem(ID_WEBSITE_LINK))->SetFont(aboutFont,true);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Things your code doesn't check: Return value from CreateFont; return value from SetFont. Also, what happens if you set the font in the .rc file itself?

Comment: CreateFont is successful. SetFont doesn't have a return. I could see a way to set the font in the .rc file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what's wrong with your code or dialog resources. But I have tried setting the font of a `CLinkCtrl` (even without using variable or typecasting), and succeeded.
I created font using `CFont::CreatePointFont`.

You first check the resource ID, also check if you create font with other approaches.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting CreatePointFont. I had already replaced the CLinkCtrl with a SysLinkCtrl, but now it seems that Visual Studio will only allow me to create an MFC Link Ctrl (not a CLinkCtrl). This control looks like a button and doesn't seem to take me to the URL when I click it. I'm not exactly sure, what's happening, but I am very confused

Comment: Though I do have VS2010 on W7, but I have tested it on VS2005 on WinXP, and it works fine. Ignore the DDX mapping for CLinkCtrl and directly change the font if you can. I don't know why you'd see just a "button"?